# Text in Android TextView should start in the first line

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am using a constrainedLayout with some TextViews. When the text in the textViews covers two lines it looks okay. But when the text only convers one line the text does not start in the first line. I added a screenhot:
[image]

So basically what I want is to shift the yellow marked textlines one level above such that the margin between the label words (Nose, Finish) and the text is not as high. It should look like the "Taste" textViews. Here is the XML code of the TextViews:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoseLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.36"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/Nose"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoseDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:gravity= "fill_vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.41"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTasteLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.47"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/Taste"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTasteDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"

       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinishLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/Finish"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinishDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63"

        />
```

Do you have an idea how I can do that? I tried different gravities (start, fill_vertical) but it did not help. I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout relies too much on `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias`. To get the vertical distribution you want, it is better to use ConstraintLayout [chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Chains). For your layout, I suggest using a vertical packed chain and removing the vertical bias and the gravities. Something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoseLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Nose"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvNoseDescription"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoseDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:text="Soft and rounded with fruity notes of red apple"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvTasteLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvNoseLabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTasteLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Taste"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvTasteDescription"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvNoseDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTasteDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A fine Sherried character, fruity aromas balanced with rich chovolate"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvFinishLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTasteLabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinishLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Finish"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvFinishDescription"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTasteDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinishDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Warm and lingering. Sweet and spoicy"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/paprika"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFinishLabel" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

which gives this appearance:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Cheticamp for your answer. I accepted and upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

you should write this in your TextView :

android:gravity="start"
or
android:gravity="start|center"

Comment: and write this :android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Thanks Majid for your answer. Unforunately the text was only shifted to the left when using your adviced commands (which I do not want). The vertical position remained unchanged. I want to change the VERTICAL position not the horizontal one.

Comment: when you have one line, what exactly do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `textAlignment` to get what you want and change the `android:layout_width` to be match_parent.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNoseDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center" // change the value to whatever you want ( ctrl + space ).
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Omar for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work.I can only shift the horizontal position of the text but not the vertical one. I want to change the VERTICAL position not the horizontal one.